# Chromecast media Host State errors

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, chromecast, smooth-streaming

I am trying to reproduce MPEG DASH, HLS and HSS(HTTP SmoothStreaming) streams by using modified sample applications provided by Google, but for now, only DASH is working.
I use:
https://github.com/googlecast/cast-custom-receiver
and
https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android

As i see here https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player?hl=en all protocols (HSS, HLS, DASH) should work without problems.

When i try to stream HSS and HLS i get this in Sample Media Receiver HUD:

Media Element State: "Error" (or "Abort")
.
.
.
Host State: "Fatal Error: code = 1"

**Does anyone know what that error represents?**
Also, sometimes i get this "Fatal Error: code = 0".

//UPDATE

I get this error when i try to cast HSS:
[2648.568s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error cast_receiver.js:19
and the link is : 
http://video3.smoothhd.com/ondemand/Turner_Sports_PGA.ism/Manifest

//UPDATE

HLS is working now. Problem is solved by setting CORS headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with codecs... I used streams encoded with VP1 video and WMAP audio codecs, so there were many errors. That is the reason for getting all those LOAD METADATA ERRORs.

And for CORS, you can use this: https://github.com/TOMODOcom/TOMODOkorz
Works like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have the same LOAD METADATA ERRORs for a m3u8 hosted by external people. How can I know what codecs they used for their m3u8? Thank you very much

Comment: I am glad i helped you. To see codecs, check fragments (.ts files) with. for example, ffmpeg -i <file_name>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what HSS is and we don't mention HSS as a supported protocol either, nor we claim we support "all" protocols. We have listed the supported protocols/variations in the link that you have mentioned.

Comment: HSS - HTTP Smooth Streaming. You misunderstood me, i meant all MENTIONED protocols from here https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media.

Comment: I don't think I misunderstood you; I haven't seen Smooth Streaming to be referred to as HSS, so that is why I said it is not in the link that you had mentioned. Anyhow, you need to open a ticket and provide the following information: (a) url of the stream that is failing, (b) your complete console log. Before filing an issue, please make sure that CORS header requirements are met

Comment: Here is refered as HSS http://blog.edgecast.com/post/55198896476/hds-hls-hss-adaptive-http-streaming-demystified.                          I have fixed a problem with HLS by meeting CORS header requirements, but problem with SmoothStreaming is still there.                   What about fatal errors, how to discover what is behind their error codes? They are cought in https://github.com/googlecast/cast-custom-receiver line 567. Something is wrong with metadata... I use URLs from here: http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/.

Comment: As I mentioned, once you are sure that CORS requirement are satisfied, you need to open a ticket with the information that I had mentioned before.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. I follow google-cast-sdk issues, so i will post my issue detailed on monday.